# Oracle: Can users view the privileges granted to them and those that are granted on their objects?

Tags: oracle

I have a question about Oracle database:
Can users view the privileges granted to them and those that are granted on their objects?

Would appreciate anyone who could share thoughts and comments.

Thanks!

Comment: Oracle and mysql are two completely different databases.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the views `user_sys_privs` and `user_tab_privs`.  And `all_tab_privs` for that matter.